# How to get dom elements using contextMenu

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I has maked a chrome extension, with a context menu options.

How to get the DOM element were the user's click with the context menu button?

EDIT:

code:

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
//here I need a clicked element.

}

chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Rellena este formulario", "contexts":[context],"id": "fill" + context});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
```

How to get clicked dom element in onClickHandler function?

The code is in background.js

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: same way as any other event ... `event.target`

Comment: see edit please. If I use event.target in background.js doesn't work.